# Get to the child of parent, jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="Slideshow homeSlideshow">
    <div class="jshowoff jshowoff-1" style="position: relative;">
    <ul style="position: relative;">
        <li class="Slide" title="Trailer" style="left: auto; right: 0px; top: auto; bottom: auto; position: relative;">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456" title="xxx"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="jshowoff-slidelinks jshowoff-1-slidelinks">
        <a class="jshowoff-slidelink-0 jshowoff-1-slidelink-0" title="undefined" href="#null" style="width: 30.3333%;">
            Trailer
        </a>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm in p class jshowoff-slidelinks. What I need, that on clicking the a inside of this p, I go to the href that's inside the li class slide.

Any idea?

It's like, go to the href to the child of parent, something of that sort.

Thing is, this is part of a slideshow code, and hence the li keeps changing as the slide moves.

Comment: it's a good idea to show your code, in this case it would be the javascript/Jquery code you are trying to make work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XdZDq/)**

```
$('.jshowoff-slidelinks.jshowoff-1-slidelinks').click(function(){

    alert($(this).closest('.jshowoff.jshowoff-1').find('li a').attr('href'));

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p a").click(function() {
  var div = $(this).parent().parent(),
    a = div.find("ul a"),
    href = a.attr("href");

  window.location = href;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[class^=jshowoff-slidelink]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).closest('.Slideshow').find('.Slide a').prop('href');
});
```

calling `.parent()` does not make use of `querySelectorAll` which has performance implications. `.closest()`, however, will, and has the better performance.

I've used `class^` or `class begins with` incase you have multiple instances of that link. window.location will tell the browser to load the string provided after the `=` which in this case, is the anchor element within the `.slide` element. We simply took the href property from this anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$("p.jshowoff-slidelinks").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).closest("div.Slideshow").find("li.Slide a").attr("href");
    if (href) {
        window.location = href;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event for click and in the event get the element and check for parent and find the anchor tag that is desired

```
 var p = $("p.jshowoff-slidelinks");
 p.click(function(){
 window.location = $(this).parent().find("ul>li>a").attr("href");
 });
```

Check the below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LSwvG/3/

Use Window.loaction to redirect

Thanks